# Compiler crashes when user inputs values into vector

Tags: c++

I'm new to stack overflow and somewhat new to programming. C++ is my first language and I'm getting more used to it with practice, however I can't seem to figure this particular problem out. I'm asking a user how many students have taken  a survey, and then asking how many movies each student has seen. The amount of movies is what I'm trying to store into the array... here's the code,

```
void FormArray(int students){

vector<int> MovieAry(5);

do{
cout << "How many students took the survey?" << endl;
cin >> students;
    if (students < 0)
        cout << "Please enter a positive value" << endl;
}while(students < 0);

for (int i = 0; i < students; i++){
    do{
        cout << "How many movies did student #" << i + 1 << " see? "; 
        cin >> MovieAry[i];
            if(MovieAry[i] < 0)
                cout << "Please enter a positive value" << endl;
            else if( MovieAry[i] > 19)
                cout << "The maximum allowed movies for this survey is 19" << endl;

    }while(MovieAry[i] < 0 || MovieAry[i] > 19);

cout << MovieAry[i] << " "; 
}

}
```

but after the last value is entered, my prorgram crashes saying my project has triggered a breakingpoint. Before I used a vector I was using a regular array, but was getting errors for accessing some weird 0x0000 number.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: also the compiler didn't crash, your program did

Comment: Vectors are stored in contiguous space and do not insert/resize when an index goes out of the bounds of the vector. MovieAry[i] will store the value in the i'th element in the vector, which is valid for values of 0-4 for i. You can either resize the vector with students. i.e. MovieAry.resize(students), or, use push_back rather than an index reference. i.e. cin >> nummovies; MovieAry.push_back(nummovies);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your `MovieAry` vector to a size of 5 and then input the actual number of students. If there are more than 5 students, you will go out of bounds on your vector. I suggest you create the vector after you have read the number of students, and set it to the required size.

Comment: Thanks Kirk, I know a vector can resize itself if another value is put into it unlike a regular array, but I changed the spot where I declared it until after students had been defined and it worked!! Thanks a million!!!